# Hessian of Morse function on $S^{n}$ mistake

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, morse-theory

I am trying to get that $f(x_{0},...,x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}$ has $index_{(0,...,0,1)}=n$

Can you find my mistake or post a partial solution?

---

**My attempt**

I evaluate df using inverse of stereographic proj. (omitting (0,...,0,-1))

$d f(\phi^{-1})=(\dfrac{4x_{1}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{2}},...,\dfrac{4x_{n}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{2}})$

and so $(0,...,0,1)$ is a critical point.

Then the first two rows for Hessian:

$Hessian(a_{1i})=(\dfrac{(8x_{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}+8x_{1}^{3})(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{2}-16x_{1}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{4}},...,\dfrac{-16x_{n}^{2}x_{1}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{3}})=(0,...,0)$

$Hessian(a_{2i})=(\dfrac{-16x_{1}^{2}x_{2}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{3}},\dfrac{(8x_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}+8x_{2}^{3})(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{2}-16x_{2}^{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{4}},...,\dfrac{-16x_{n}^{2}x_{2}}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})^{3}})=(0,...,0)$

So the Hessian is just zeroes.

But the $index_{(0,...,0,1)}=n$. I am supposed to get n-negative values in the diagonal.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the first entry, you compute the derivative of a quotient
$$
\dfrac{f'g - f g'}{g^2}
$$
where $f = 4 x_1^2 \sum_i x_i^2$ and $g = (1 + \sum x_i^2)^2$.

The $f g'$ term should be

$$
\left(4 x_1^2 \sum_i x_i^2\right) \left(  2 (1 + \sum_i x_i^2) 2 x_1 \right) \\ 
16 x_1^3 (\sum_i x_i^2 )(1 + \sum_i x_i^2).
$$

Presumably by plugging in $n = 1$ into your formula above, you can see where you went off the rails.

You seem to have $8$ instead of $16$.   (This is the only term I checked).

I don't see, however, why computing only the first row of the Hessian suffices to show you that the eigenvalues are not all negative -- can you explain your reasoning? Or am I supposed to see, from the first row, the pattern of the others? If so, I still don't see why the e-values can't all be negative. (Except that maybe your swapping 8 for 16 would ruin it...)

Later comment, now that you've fixed the $8$ vs $16$ thing:

Looking more closely at your work, let's consider the unit circle in 2-space. Stereographic projection from the south pole takes the unit disk to the upper hemisphere (in this case, the interval $[-1, 1]$ to the upper circle) by 
$$
(x, 0) \mapsto (\frac{2x}{1 + x^2} , \frac{1-x^2}{1 + x^2})
$$

The derivative you want to compute is 
\begin{align}
d(f \circ \phi^{-1}) &= d(\frac{1-x^2}{1 + x^2})/dx \\
 &= \frac{(1-x^2)' (1 + x^2) - (1-x^2)(1 + x^2)'}{(1 + x^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{(-2x) (1 + x^2) - (1-x^2)(2x)}{(1 + x^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{(-2x - 2x^3) - (2x - 2x^3)}{(1 + x^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{(-2x - 2x^3) + (-2x + 2x^3)}{(1 + x^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{- 4x}{(1 + x^2)^2}
\end{align}

Since, near $x = 0$, this is just $-4x$ to first order, the second derivative at $0$ will be $-4$, and not $0$. Presumably by plugging in $n = 1$ to your formula above you can discover where you went off the rails.

Lemme go ahead and compute the second derivative:

\begin{align}
H &= d(\frac{- 4x}{(1 + x^2)^2} )/dx \\
 &= \frac{(- 4x)'(1 + x^2)^2 + 4x( (1+x^2)^2 )'}{ (1 + x^2)^4} \\
 &= \frac{- 4(1 + x^2)^2 + 4x( 2(1+x^2)(2x) )}{ (1 + x^2)^4} \\
 &= \frac{- 4(1 + x^2)^2 + 16x^2(1+x^2)}{ (1 + x^2)^4} \\
 &= \frac{ (-4(1 + x^2) + 16x^2)(1+x^2)}{ (1 + x^2)^4} \\
 &= \frac{ (-4 + 12x^2)(1+x^2)}{ (1 + x^2)^4} 
\end{align}
Now plug in $x = 0$ to get
\begin{align}
H_0 &= \left. \frac{ (-4 + 12x^2)(1+x^2)}{ (1 + x^2)^4} \right|_{x=0} \\
 &=  \frac{ (-4 )(1)}{ (1)^4}  \\
&= -4.
\end{align}

Comment: because there supposed to be n negative values along the diagonal.

Comment: also,the hessian is supposed to be non-singular ($det\neq 0$).

Comment: I've edited my response to do the computation correctly for the case $n = 1$; you can compare your work to mine by plugging in $n = 1$ in your formula and see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Cartesian parametrization instead of stereographic coordinates? You have
$$
x_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}}
  = 1 - \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2} + O(\|\mathbf{x}\|^4).
$$

Comment: is this right $df(x)=(\frac{-x_{1}}{\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}},...,\frac{-x_{n}}{\sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}})$

Comment: but I need a hessian that is different for $x_{n+1}=1$ and -1 because the (0,...,0,1) and (0,...,0,-1) have different index.

Comment: (i) At the origin, the Hessian of $O(\|\mathbf{x}\|^4)$ vanishes; calculating the entire Hessian isn't necessary. (ii) The suggested parametrization lives in a chart near $(0,\dots,0,1)$; you need the negative square root near the antipode. :)